# How to suppress "Update Links" on Workbooks.Open while outputting the filename to a text file

Tags: excel, vba, xlsx, xls

I am using a macro to recursively move through thousands of xls files and convert them to xlsx. Everything is going smoothly, and I have used the `UpdateLinks:=False` option of `Workbooks.Open`to suppress the alerts when opening those workbooks. I would, however, like to output the filename to some sort of text file, or even just a worksheet whenever a workbook is opened with links in need of updating. The actual process of collecting those names shouldn't be an issue for me, but I can not figure out a way to both suppress the warnings, but *also* trigger the output of that filename.

For example, my thought is that I could so something like:

```
 Set wkbConvert = Workbooks.Open(fFile.Path, UpdateLinks:=False)
 If linksNeedToBeUpdated Then
      'concatenate fFile.name somewhere
 End If
```

but I'm not sure how to catch that `linksNeedToBeUpdated` value if I'm suppressing the warnings and not triggering any errors. I thought about using `On Error Go To` and discarding the `UpdateLinks:=False` option, but this will happen on *all* errors, like corrupted files, or permissions issues, and I don't want that.

My full code is below.

```vb
     Sub convertXLStoXLSX(ByVal directoryPath As String)

         Dim FSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject
         Dim strConversionPath As String
         Dim subFolderPath As String
         Dim fFile As file
         Dim fFolder As Folder
         Dim fSubFolder As Folder
         Dim wkbConvert As Workbook

         Application.ScreenUpdating = False
         Application.enableEvents = False

         strConversionPath = directoryPath

         Set FSO = New Scripting.FileSystemObject

         ' Check if the folder exists
         If FSO.FolderExists(strConversionPath) Then
             Set fFolder = FSO.GetFolder(strConversionPath)

             ' Loop through files, find the .xls files
             For Each fFile In fFolder.Files
                 If Right(fFile.name, 4) = ".xls" Or Right(fFile.name, 4) = ".XLS" Then
                     Application.StatusBar = "Converting " & fFile.name
                     Application.displayAlerts = False

                     Set wkbConvert = Workbooks.Open(fFile.Path, UpdateLinks:=False)

                     ' Save as XML workbook - if file contains macros change FileFormat:=52
                     wkbConvert.SaveAs FSO.BuildPath(fFile.ParentFolder, left(fFile.name, Len(fFile.name) - 4)) & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=51
                     wkbConvert.Close SaveChanges:=False

                     ' Delete original file
                     fFile.Delete Force:=True

                     Application.StatusBar = False
                     Application.displayAlerts = True
                 End If
             Next fFile

             'move recursively into folders in this directory
             For Each fSubFolder In fFolder.SubFolders
                 Application.StatusBar = "Checking Folder " & fSubFolder.Path
                 subFolderPath = strConversionPath & fSubFolder.name & Application.PathSeparator
                 convertXLStoXLSX (subFolderPath)
                 Application.StatusBar = False
             Next fSubFolder

         End If

         Application.enableEvents = True
         Application.ScreenUpdating = True

     End Sub
```

Again, once I figure out how to detect the "links" status of the file being opened while still suppressing the warning I can handle collecting the file names from there. Unless anyone has a completely different strategy that they would recommend, I should be able to figure out the rest myself. Thank you.

Comment: https://www.exceltrick.com/how_to/how-to-find-external-links-or-references-in-excel/

Comment: Thanks. I don't think this quite solves my problem. I don't want to list the links, just the files that would prompt the problem links warning. I'm converting thousands of files so I need them to open without addressing the links issue now. I just need to make note of the hundreds of files that did trigger this warning. If this resource does address that, please let me know. But I didn't find anything helpful there. I appreciate it though.

Comment: Using "method 3" you can try checking whether `wkbConvert.LinkSources(xlExcelLinks)` is empty, then write the filename if not.

Comment: OK I see what you're asking - not how to detect links, but how to detect *stale* links?  I'm not sure how you could do that, since you'd have to check each link source.

Comment: Right. But not even to that level. On Workbooks.Open, if the file contains broken links, it puts up a warning which is suppressed by the "UpdateLinks" option. What I want to do is still suppress the link update dialog but catch some sort of value that indicates that the *file* contains broken links. I don't need to know the files the links call out to, just whether or not the file that I just tried to open would trigger a link update dialog.

Comment: https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/849481-find-broken-links-excel-2013-a.html

Comment: Interesting. This might be helpful. I'll take a look and get back to you. Thanks!

Comment: I think your problem is there's no way to detect broken links without having Excel try to update them - you could try adding `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` to suppress any prompts while that happens.  And of course it's going to potentially make your update process much slower.

Comment: Exactly. I'm testing now to see if suppress the prompts still allows me to detect an appropriate status once the file is open. I'll let you know what I find